# Filling 2D array results in Bad operand types for binary operator '%' error

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to write a method that takes in an int 2D array
that is randomly filled with 0s and 1s
and prints out how many 0s and 1s there are. But the code below results in the error saying "Bad operand types for binary operator '%' error". Please help me fix this.

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Randomfilled {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arry = new int[3][4];
        arrays(arry);
    }

    public static void arrays(int[][] arry) {

        Random n = new Random();
        int z = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arry[0].length; j++) {
                arry[i][j] = Math.abs(n % 2);

                if (arry[i][j] == 0) {
                    z++;
                }
                if (arry[i][j] == 1) {
                    x++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What needs fixing? Please describe the desired and actual results of your code. _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."_

Comment: `Math.abs(n % 2)` should be `n.nextInt(2)`

Comment: You could use `arry[i][j] = n.nextBoolean() ? 1 : 0;`. But your instructions say takes "an int 2D array that is randomly filled with 0s and 1s"; I believe you should be filling the array before calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

Array data insertion error!

```
      for (int i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arry[0].length; j++) {
            arry[i][j] = n.nextInt(2);//Change

            if (arry[i][j] == 0) {
                z++;
            }
            if (arry[i][j] == 1) {
                x++;
            }

        }
```